# Cant fetch SharePoint list column items with JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

I cant run my code. I get this error message:

> 0x800a139e - Runtime Errors in JavaScript : The property or field has not been initialized . There has been no request or has not been performed. It might need to be requested specifically.

I created an app (custom list) on developer site. In that list I created 3 columns (Title, Status and Responsible). And I also added some items to fetch them with my code. It displays column titles but when I want to fetch `Resposible` column it give me the error. In `appManifest` I added Web to Full Control.

```
'use strict';

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var parentContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);
var parentWeb = parentContext.get_web();
var listitemCollection = parentWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("CaseList").getItems("");


$(document).ready(function () {

    context.load(listitemCollection);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
});

function onSuccess() {

    var itemString1 = "";
    var itemString2 = "";
    var itemString3 = "";

    var listEnumerator = listitemCollection.getEnumerator();
    var currentItem;

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        if (currentItem.get_item('Status') == "New") {
            itemString1 += "<br/>" + currentItem.get_item('Title') + " " + currentItem.get_item('Responsible');
        }
        else if (currentItem.get_item('Status') == "Started") {
            currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
            itemString2 += "<br/>" + currentItem.get_item('Title') + " " + currentItem.get_item('Responsible');
        }
        else if (currentItem.get_item('Status') == "Finished") {
            currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
            itemString3 += "<br/>" + currentItem.get_item('Title') + " " + currentItem.get_item('Responsible');
        }
    }

    $("#Show1").html(itemString1);
    $("#Show2").html(itemString2);
    $("#Show3").html(itemString3);
}

function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert("Error:" + args.get_message());
}

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request for additional fields using

```
 context.load(listitemCollection, 'Include(Responsible,Status)');
```

Comment: I tried with that. But now I get a new error. "Error: Coloumn Responsible is not there. It may has been deleted by another user." Which I find it very strange. When I go to my developer site I can see my list with that column name.

Comment: At least the previous error is gone.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct internal name and not display name

Comment: Okey I can try that. But when I add a column in the list how can I see the internal name? My list is in developer site. The column names are "Ansvarig", "Totalsumma" and "Responsible".

Comment: You can open the fields from List Settings and check URL query string `Field=`

Comment: Thank you! Finally it works. But in my opinion display name should be also the internal name otherwise you have to click every column name to get the internal name.

Comment: Just a quick question. I got a column name called "Totalsumma" there I have stored numberic items like "342", "3242" etc. How can I fetch the highest value from that column. In this case "3242" is the highest value.

Comment: Users keep changing display name. So internal will be similar to the first display name (It removes spaces and other characters) also it makes it unique by adding numbers at the end

Comment: Like this?                                                                                             function totalSumma() {
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var listItems1 = listitemCollection.get_item(query);
    context.load(listitemCollection);
    var textCaml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Totalsumma' Ascending='True'/></Geq></Where></Query></View>";
    query.set_viewXml(textCaml);
    $("#Visa4").html(textCaml);

Comment: Sorry the code got messed up in my comment.

Comment: Please keep the comments related to the above question, not to new questions!

Comment: Okey, thank you Amal. I will create a new question how to fetch max value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for some items that column value is null or empty.

Check this condition each time you are retrieving some column values:

```
item.get_item('internalColumnName')!= null
```